# Ubuntu 18.04 update issue

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04, updates

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. It is having the following update issue when running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

```
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Fetched 83.2 kB in 4s (23.0 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Results of `sudo apt list --upgradable` :

```
Listing... Done
nodejs/bionic-updates 8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.2]
nodejs-dev/bionic-updates 8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.2]
```

Results of `sudo apt upgrade` :

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libasan3-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libasan4-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libasan4-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libatomic1-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libatomic1-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libc6-armel-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross but it is not installed
 libc6-armhf-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross but it is not installed
 libc6-dev-armel-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-dev-armel-cross but it is not installed
 libcilkrts5-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libcilkrts5-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libgcc1-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libgcc1-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libgomp1-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libgomp1-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libhfasan4-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libhfatomic1-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libhfcilkrts5-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libhfgomp1-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libhfstdc++6-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libhfubsan0-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libsfasan4-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libsfatomic1-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libsfcilkrts5-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libsfgomp1-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libsfstdc++6-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libsfubsan0-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libstdc++6-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libstdc++6-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libubsan0-armel-cross : Depends: libc6-armel-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
 libubsan0-armhf-cross : Depends: libc6-armhf-cross (&gt;= 2.27) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Results of `sudo apt --fix-broken install` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cpp-7-arm-linux-gnueabi cpp-arm-linux-gnueabi gcc-7-arm-linux-gnueabi gcc-7-arm-linux-gnueabi-base gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi libasan4-armel-cross libatomic1-armel-cross libc6-armhf-armel-cross libcilkrts5-armel-cross
  libgcc-7-dev-armel-cross libhfasan4-armel-cross libhfatomic1-armel-cross libhfcilkrts5-armel-cross libhfgcc-7-dev-armel-cross libhfgcc1-armel-cross libhfgomp1-armel-cross libhfstdc++6-armel-cross
  libhfubsan0-armel-cross libstdc++6-armel-cross libubsan0-armel-cross
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6-armel-cross libc6-armhf-cross libc6-dev-armel-cross
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-armel-cross libc6-armhf-cross libc6-dev-armel-cross
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,972 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 424757 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-armel-cross_2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-armel-cross (2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-armel-cross_2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/ld-2.27.so.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Preparing to unpack .../libc6-armhf-cross_2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-armhf-cross (2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-armhf-cross_2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/ld-2.27.so.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-armel-cross_2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-armel-cross (2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-armel-cross_2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/Mcrt1.o.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-armel-cross_2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-armhf-cross_2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-armel-cross_2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try to `apt -f install`

Comment: Hi, i tried that. It throughs the same error as above.

Comment: Try to remove this problem package and reinstall in manualy:
`apt purge libc6-dev-armel-cross`

Download this package from here: `https://packages.debian.org/sid/libc6-dev-armel-cross`
Then `dpkg -i libc6-dev-armel-cross_2.27-6cross1_all.deb`
And try to `apt update && apt upgrade again`

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I did the same again, initially it was not installing then i intall it with "ignore-depends flag". After installing, the apt upgrade is giving the same  error for "apt --fix-broken install"

Comment: I have read the posts regarding the same issue, don't know how i am not able to remove the package completely and install that again

Comment: The issue is roaming somewhere around "Mcrt1.o.dpkg-new'" , as it is giving error for dpkg installatoin - dpkg: error processing archive libc6-dev-armhf-cross_2.27-3ubuntu1cross1.1_all.deb (--install):
 unable to open '/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/Mcrt1.o.dpkg-new': No such file or directory

Comment: Hi, just wanted to tell that after "ibc6-dev" installation that you suggested, i did "-f dist-upgrade". And finally its done. Nothing was giving result only this command gave result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem with *Mcrt1.o.dpkg-new* and the only working solution was to remove all packages with dependency problems together.
In my case the list was:

```
apt remove libc6-dev-armel-cross libstdc++-7-dev-armel-cross libstdc++-5-dev-armel-cross g++-5-arm-linux-gnueabi  g++-7-arm-linux-gnueabi g++-arm-linux-gnueabi libasan2-armel-cross  libasan4-armel-cross libatomic1-armel-cross libcilkrts5-armel-cross libgcc1-armel-cross libgomp1-armel-cross libstdc++6-armel-cross libubsan0-armel-cross libgcc-5-dev-armel-cross libgcc-7-dev-armel-cross gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi gcc-7-arm-linux-gnueabi  gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```